# react native - react-hook-form onSubmit not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create a form using `react-hook-form`, the only thing which is not working is the `onSubmit` callback, and I'm following the docs exactly, but still, the callback isn't firing, although, when I press the submit button, it did performs validation but not `onSubmit` callback, so then I tried to reproduce the same code on `snack.expo` and there the same thing, the exact same thing is working... I didn't know what to do so I'm here posting the question...

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Button,
    View,
    TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const SignIn = () => {
    const {
        control,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<FormData>({
        defaultValues: {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        },
    });

    const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
        console.log('data: ', data);
    };

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.root}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Sign In</Text>

            {/* email textinput */}
            <Controller
                control={control}
                rules={{
                    required: {
                        value: true,
                        message: 'E-mail is required.',
                    },
                    pattern: {
                        value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
                        message: 'Enter a valid email address',
                    },
                }}
                render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput
                            value={value}
                            onBlur={onBlur}
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder="Email"
                            onChangeText={onChange}
                            placeholderTextColor="gray"
                        />
                    </View>
                )}
                name="email"
            />
            {errors.email && (
                <Text>{errors.email.message}</Text>
            )}

            {/* password textinput */}
            <Controller
                control={control}
                rules={{
                    minLength: {
                        value: 6,
                        message: 'Password should be at least 6 characters',
                    },
                    maxLength: {
                        value: 20,
                        message: 'Password should be at most 20 characters',
                    },
                    required: {
                        value: true,
                        message: 'Password is required.',
                    },
                }}
                render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput
                            value={value}
                            onBlur={onBlur}
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder="Password"
                            onChangeText={onChange}
                            placeholderTextColor="gray"
                            secureTextEntry
                        />
                    </View>
                )}
                name="password"
            />
            {errors.password && (
                <Text>{errors.password.message}</Text>
            )}

            {/* submit button */}
            <Button title="submit" onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default SignIn;
```

First I thought there might be some errors due to which it is not able to trigger the `onSubmit` callback, but nope, I confirmed it that there were no errors...

Second, I tried this solution https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/2321#issuecomment-906964945, didn't work, plus it hanged the app and the screen went full black...

So at last I decided to re-produce it in snack.expo using the exact code which I'm using and it was working as expected... :(. Here is the link for the expo and above code from my actual app https://snack.expo.dev/@rog9274/e85959?platform=web

So can someone shed some light on this issue?

Thank you

Comment: why is your `form` not enclosed in a `<Form>` tag?

Comment: @yeln because this is react native...

Answer (score 0):

After lots of debugging, I noticed that nothing was logging, even a simple `console.log('hello')` was not logging, (I ran the project using `expo run:ios` / `expo run:android`), I quit it and **rebuilt the project using XCode** and now everything is working, all console logs are working and even the `handleSubmit` callback is working... That was really weird, maybe the expo terminal is bugged? Don't really know.